# Change tray icons size in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: icons, system-tray

Is there a way to change the system tray icons size in Ubuntu 21.04? They are awfully small and notification indications are almost non visible.

[image]

EDIT:
Attached a snapshot for clarity.

Comment: @UnKNOWn -- added the picture. Please check the slack icon on the right section. I need to change sizes of the tray icons. Thanks :)

Comment: Its just an example. Any icons regardles Slack, Skype etc they are very small. I have tried Gnome-tweaks but it enlarges entire view.

Comment: Hmm not sure about that whether they are snap packages.

Comment: @UnKNOWn this is exactly I wanted. Kindly paste this solution as an answer and I'll be more than happy to accep it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the Ubuntu's system extension Ubuntu App Indicator and then use this https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/ official gnome-shell-extension.

Then from settings of this extension adjust the size with in the limits specified.

[image: Hi]

Comment: Also working for Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: icons here are too large in width I dont get why (each icon do not need so much space), so I was looking for a way to lower the width. With this extension, if I click align center or left it will provide enough space for all icons to expand and show also the text on them, what also solves the problem, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Install the Gnome extension [Taskbar 2020](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2506/taskbar-updated/).
Open the extension and select the 'panels'. Increase the size of the tray icons by increasing the pixels of 'Adjust Panel content size'